# Parent style depending on build variant

Tags: android, android-styles, android-build-flavors

I have two themes defined in `themes.xml`.

Those two themes are applied in the manifest via productFlavors:

build.gradle

```xml
productFlavors {
            flavor1 {
                dimension "theme"
                manifestPlaceholders = [
                        appTheme: "@style/Theme1"
                ]
            }

            flavor2 {
                dimension "theme"
                manifestPlaceholders = [
                        appTheme: "@style/Theme2"
                ]
            }
    }
```

manifest.xml

```xml
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="${appTheme}" >
```

This works correctly, depending on the build variant selected, different themes are applied.

Now I want to integrate Stripe SDK witch declares a Style called [StripeDefaultTheme](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/802fde8f3cef2f2c74250f5567aecc13c8b98915/stripe/res/values/styles.xml#L3).

In this style I want to override the `colorPrimary` and `colorAccent` with the values of my own themes.

Is it possible to declare a parent to a style that is determined by a Build Variant ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making two separate themes, you can have just one theme that varies depending on different flavor. To do so you just need to override styles.xml files in the corresponding flavor's source set. For example,

1. The `AppTheme` in the main source set should contain the stripe related theming only,

   **{app_module_dir}/src/main/res/values/styles.xml**

   ```
   <style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <!-- Stripe related values here. -->
   </style>
   ```
2. Copy the contents of Theme1 into flavor1's source set

   **{app_module_dir}/src/flavor1/res/values/styles.xml**

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
       <!-- Theme1 contents here. -->
   </style>
   ```
3. Copy the contents of Theme2 into flavor2's source set

   **{app_module_dir}/src/flavor2/res/values/styles.xml**

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
       <!-- Theme2 contents here. -->
   </style>
   ```

**Mannifest**

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

**build.gradle**

```
productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            dimension "theme"
        }

        flavor2 {
            dimension "theme"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Theme1 & Theme2 may have common BaseTheme that you can override in flavor res dir styles.xml file.